# Spring tests inpact on service transactions

Tags: spring, testing, transactions

I am using @Transactional for my JUnit tests (main advantage is rollback of changes within one test) but I have small problem that this influence my service transactions. So for example this is

my service :

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ServiceImpl
```

my unit test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/test-context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class TestService 

@Test
public void testNumberTransaction() {
Entity a = new Entity();
Entity b = new Entity();
service.add(a);
service.add(b);
}
```

So naively I expected to have two separate transactions for service.add() but unless I use @nontransactional on the test method it runs inside one transaction (but then it does not roll back after test).

Is this expected?Can I alter it with some configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's expected. `Propagation.REQUIRED` (which is the default) means: execute in the existing transaction if it exists. Else, create a transaction and commit it at the end of the method.

So yes, if the whole test method is transactional, both service calls will execute in the context of the test transaction.

Note that since the service is annotated with `REQUIRED`, it's supposed to work if a transaction already exists. This makes the test valid: it tests your service in the context of an existing transaction. If you want a service to execute in its own dedicated transaction, it should be annotated with `REQUIRES_NEW`. But of course, if it's the case, you won't be able to rollback the service transaction by executing the test in a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

By default (`REQUIRES` is the default propagation behavior) if the transaction already exists, your service method will not create new one but rather join to the one that exists. In your case it is the transaction created by the Spring test framework (the one that will be rolled back).

You can alter this behavior by setting propagation to `REQUIRES_NEW`. However because now you business `add` method runs within a new transaction, once you leave this method the transaction will be committed rather than rolled back. By default, since all transactions are joined in the JUnit test transaction, all changes made to the database are rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

The `@Transactional` defines the demarcation line. Annotating the class is equivalent with annotating each public method of the class, the line of demarcation is still the method (in your case, the `testNumberTransaction()`). The commit/rollback decision will be taken at the demarcation point, that is when returning from your test method. Regardless of whether you specify `REQUIRES` or `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation, the actual transaction unit is the same, your `testNumberTransaction()` method so the two `service.add(...)` calls will always be executed in the same transaction.

If your goal is to always roll back your transactions after the test, then simply removing the `@Transactional` annotation (or putting @nontransactional as you mentioned) should do.

If, on the other hand, you want to FORCE a new transaction for each `service.add(...)` invocation, you could either create a wrapper for your service class where you have an `add(...)` method that is annotated with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) and call the wrapped `service` instance `add(...)` method from there. OR you could add some declarative transaction management in your spring test context that adds transaction advise for your `service.add(...)` method. Read more in the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation) on how to add declarative transaction support using the `<tx:XXX>` tags.

Comment: Removing @Transactional from the test method won't rollback the transaction: there won't be any transaction for the test. a transaction will start when the service method is called, and will commit when the service method returns.

Comment: True, clumsy formulation on my part. Removing the @Transactional annotation will prevent the transaction manager from creating a transaction in the java layer. Most databases will, however, always create an implicit transaction for each session and if you set auto-commit to off (which is default, IIRC), no transaction will behave the same way as transaction which always rolls back. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Err, no. Removing the Transactional from the *test* method will make the test run outside of any transactional context, but Spring will still start a transaction for each service method call, since the *service* method is annotated with Transactional. The actual transactional work done by the service (which probably updates some database) will thus be done in a transaction and committed, unless the service itself throws a runtime exception.

Comment: Assuming the service method IS annotated @Transactional, that is. My point was that many, if not most databases will always create a transaction for each SQL command you execute so there will always be a transactional context in play. You can choose not to have Spring pick up that transactional context (ie, not annotating @Transactional), but it will still be there. If you set auto commit to "false", it will never commit and your updates will never be reflected. Or you can set auto commit to "true", in which case your updates will always be committed.

Comment: The service **is** annotated with Transactional. It's written in the OP's question.

Comment: So it is. Well, I claim temporary blindness and attempt to quietly leave the room. :)